# Selecting row from DB using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a row from the DB using php, i've made an html form that's supposed to take a book title from users and gets the review from the DB about this book, and then post it in an input text, the form's action leads to the following function :

```
function GetReview($BookTitle)
{
require'DB.php';
if(empty($_POST['BookTitle']))
    {
        echo " You must enter a book name!";
        return false;
    }

$BookTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($BookTitle);

$q="Select Reviews from Users_Booklist where (Book_Title like '%" .$BookTitle."%');";
if(!mysql_query($q,$con))
{
die("Error".mysql_error());
}
else
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($q);
?>
<html>
<head><title>Delete Review </title>
</head>
<body> 
<br>
<form name="DeleteReview " action="DeleteReviewsFunction.php" method="post">
Review: <input type="text" name="Review" size="200" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"/>            
<input type="submit" value="Delete Review" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
}
GetReview($_POST['BookTitle'])
```

However, it leads me to the next form with nothing in the input text and this warning:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in     C:\AppServ\www\GetReview.php on line 20
```

I've searched and tried different code but still same result.
Could anyone please tell me where the error is???... Thanks

Comment: The first example of http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php shows the reason

Comment: You're trying to fetch a result form your query **STRING**. You need to fetch from the value returned by the mysql_query() call.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3):

```
$qq = mysql_query($q,$con);
if(!$qq) {
// (...)

$row = mysql_fetch_row($qq);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to be a lot of help, but your question seems to be where the error is occuring, and I can tell you that.

It's in the `$row = mysql_fetch_row($q);` line.

You can tell this because the error record starts with `mysql_fetch_row()`, and the above line is the only mention of `mysql_fetch_row()` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL query by printing the output of $q variable with:

> echo $q;

Now, try to execute it from your MySQL client. Collect the results (if there are) and check for errors.

A suggestion: If you want, you can use a tool like [ezSQL](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql) that can be very useful (especially for code organization)